# join 2 tables of first row of tabl1 to first row of table 2

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables `emptimein` and `emptimeoutOT`. Both have the same fields.

```
table1
Emptimein
ID  Date  TimeIn

table2
ID  Date  TimeOutOT
```

I want to join both tables to combine the first row of the `emptimein` table and 
`emptimeout` table

I want a result like this

```
ID  Timein  TimeOutOT
```

Comment: Do you have any relation between these two tables, May be like `ID` columns will be same in both table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: id to id retion....im using microsoft sql

Comment: If you'd provide some DDL (CREATE TABLE Emptimein(...)) and esp. some DML (INSERT INTO Emptimein VALUES(...)), then we would be better placed to help. Also, and very important, what database server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1#

```
select Etimein.ID,Etimein.TimeIN,
Etimeout.TimeOutOT
from databasename.Emptimein as Etimein left outer join 
databasename.Emptimeout as Etimeout on Etimein.ID=Etimeout.ID
and Etimein.date=Etimeout.date
where Etimein.date between 'yyyy-mm-dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd'
group by Etimein.id
order by Etimein.id
;
```

CASE 2#

```
select Etimein.ID,Etimein.TimeIN,
Etimeout.TimeOutOT
from databasename.Emptimein as Etimein left outer join 
databasename.Emptimeout as Etimeout on Etimein.ID=Etimeout.ID
and Etimein.date=Etimeout.date
where Etimeout.date between 'yyyy-mm-dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd'
group by Etimein.id
order by Etimein.id
;
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'EmpTimeIn.Att_TimeIn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query:

```
SELECT EI.ID,EI.Timein,EO.TimeOutOT FROM emptimein EI 
LEFT JOIN emptimeoutOT EO ON EI.ID = EO.ID 
AND Etimein.date = Etimeout.date
WHERE Etimein.date BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

**Let me know in case I misunderstood the requirements.**

Comment: Downvoted: a) incorrect formatting b) incorrect query (no date checked)